# How to use regex for number marchers in pact contract interactions

Tags: javascript, pact

I have a situation like example you can take this api

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/45204710?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow`

This will return `view_count` as number. And that can be dynamic in nature. When I create pact interaction for these kinda response how can I add marchers for number.
I tried this but not working.

`"view_count": term({
      matcher: '[0-9]',
      generate: 123
}),`

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported. You should use a `like(123)` instead.

Comment: `view_count ` so dynamic man. I can't use like 123,124,125, etc :(

Comment: Using `like(123)` will return the `view_count: 123` in your consumer tests, but will assert that the `view_count` is an integer when verifying the provider. It's designed to be used in the situation where the response will have dynamic values, but the consumer test needs a concrete example to work with. Have a read of this: https://github.com/realestate-com-au/pact/wiki/Understanding-Request-Matching